# User authetication with max login attemtps

Tags: php, authentication, session

First off let me know if this is not the correct place for this discussion!

We have decided to move our sessions to the Database layer in our application and handle the users state from there. One of the important issues that we hoped to resolve was user authentication to stop from brute forcing accounts by blocking login attempts from both the session layer (built from a database entry) as well as on the account layer - with an optional toggle to remove the account specific lockout for users as the potential remains for bad actors to then attempt to lock a legitimate user out of their account by spamming the account login - but the tradeoff here is then the account cannot be brute forced. This may be a toggle for specific accounts in the future if we decide the build the app around that idea more.

The current script for sessions includes a function (which i have included below) that you can call on the login event called `check_login_attempts_exceeded` and will return TRUE if they have been or FALSE if they have not been - Allowing you to either accept the login attempt, or block the attempt before it even hits the login server.

Basically, the user flow would work something like this:

```
Authenticated user:: 
  We will just return FALSE right away because they are already logged in and don't 
  need to know this information on their own account. It does allow for them to check
  other users with different user ids since they may be an admin and have a need for
  that information? This is primarily designed for Guest logins anyways before the
  user has been Authenticated in the system.

Spider::
  Treat them as a guest account so the spider mechanism isn't exploited by people
  to try and bypass the users login limit.

Guest account::
1) The system confirms they are a guest and continues, or returns FALSE if they
   are already signed in to an account matching the ID of their user id -> this is
   the Authenticated users section above.

2) Check if the user has a login lockout flag set on the SESSION. We don't care
   about specific users **yet**, but we will check them afterwards.

   NO:: 
      1). Check if the user is at the max attempts in the system:

        YES:: 
          1). If the user is at the maximum attempts but doesn't have the flag set
              for some reason, we add the login_lockout globally and add it to the
              users SESSION in the database.
          2). Return TRUE so the system knows they've exceeded max attempts

        NO::
          1). If the user has a supplied ID greater than 0, they can check if a
              specific account is over. Since the flag is not yet set, this is the
              only time this can be checked for specific accounts. This will be a
              time code on the ACCOUNT level and if it is passed we handle it [1]
              way, and if it's not passed we handle it [2] way.

              [1]-> The lockout time on the ACCOUNT level is still in the future
                    so we are going to return TRUE because this account level check
                    shows the account is locked regardless of this SESSION and we
                    want to prevent brute forcing of accounts. The downside to this
                    method is a specific user can be locked out of their accounts
                    legitimately if a bad actor spams their login name.
                    
              [2]-> The lockout on the ACCOUNT level is in the past, so lets set
                    the login attempts and lockout time on the ACCOUNT level to 0
                    for both and return FALSE since the timeout is no longer on
                    and the account hasn't exceeded it's limit! :)
              
          2). The user id wasn't supplied so we assume the user hasn't gone over
              yet because the flag isn't set yet by any previous condition and the
              lockout time doesn't exist either so we return FALSE :)

      2). Return FALSE as a failsafe incase the user id wasn't set and they are
          not at the limit meaning they've passed the test and not exceeded attempts

   YES::
      1). The user has the flag set so lets see if the timeout on the flag has 
          expired and remove it if it has

        YES:: 
          1). Remove the flag, update the session and reset the attempts and the
              lockout time to 0 again. Ideally return FALSE now, but we need to
              check the ACCOUNT specific timeout as well just in case that one is
              still set.
```

The last portion is the bit I am wanting to be sure of. Basically, if the user HAS a time flag on their SESSION, we need to check if its expired and remove it if it is - but then the ACCOUNT layer inside of this may be time locked separately so we need to check that, remove it if its expired, or return as invalid if its not expired.

I am doing this with the following code (PHP) and have commented as much of the code as possible to explain the steps and where I am at:

```
// Check if the user has exceeded their login attempts, and if they are locked
// out return TRUE, and if the lockout has expired, remove it from the session
// AND the user account if it is set - Optional return time to unlock
function check_login_attempts_exceeded($database, $config, $userid = 0, $return_time = FALSE) {
    
    // Set the time of now for checking if they are past the lockout expiry
    $time = CURRENT_TIME;
    $userid = (int) $userid;
    $unauthenticated_user = FALSE;
    
    // Check if this user is logged in - If they are, we can return false
    // since this user is already logged in and doesn't need to have attempts
    // logged for them anymore.
    if ($userid > 0 && $userid == $this->userid) {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        $unauthenticated_user = TRUE;
    }

    // If the user is a guest, we can process the request since it's not important
    // otherwise. This condition should always be true, but better safe than sorry?
    if ($unauthenticated_user) {

        // If the login_timeout isn't set we can check if the attempts are over
        // and set it otherwise, it must be set so we will see if its expired
        if (!$this->login_timeout || $this->login_timeout == 0) {

            // Check the global lockout first - if it above the max then we will
            // ignore the fact that the user is over since we're not there yet
            if ($this->login_attempts >= $config->general->max_login_trys) {
                $this->login_timeout = (int) $time + ($config->general->lockout_time * 60);
                $database->update_prepared_query("sessions", array("lockout_time" => $this->login_timeout), array("sid" => $this->session_id));
                return TRUE;
            }

            // Now lets check the specific user case, because we know that the
            // above has been handled and returned already
            if ($userid > 0) {
                $user_info = $database->prepared_select("users", "WHERE uid = ? LIMIT 1", array($userid), "loginattempts, loginlockoutexpiry");
                if ($user_info) {
                    $user_specific_loginattempts = $user_info["loginattempts"];
                    $user_specific_loginexpiry = $user_info["loginlockoutexpiry"];

                    // If this specific user is over the max attempts, then we return
                    // true because they're over the max attempt
                    if ($user_specific_loginattempts >= $config->general->max_login_trys) {

                        // We also want to see if their expiry is over the max limit
                        // and it if is, we will return true, if it is expired,
                        // lets remove it and set these back to 0 and return false!
                        if ($user_specific_loginexpiry > $time) {
                            if ($return_time) {
                                $secsleft = (int) ($user_specific_loginexpiry - $time);
                                $hoursleft = floor($secsleft / 3600);
                                $minsleft = floor(($secsleft / 60) % 60);
                                $secsleft = floor($secsleft % 60);
                                return array("hours" => $hoursleft, "minutes" => $minsleft, "seconds" => $secsleft);
                            }
                            return TRUE;
                        } else {
                            // This user specific timeout has expired, so lets
                            // remove it from the system and let the user attempt
                            // a login!
                            $database->update_prepared_query("users", array("loginattempts" => 0, "loginlockoutexpiry" => 0), array("uid" => $userid));
                            return FALSE;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    
                    // There was no user information found for this id, so we can't
                    // return a result and we will just return false instead
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }

            // Must not be over yet then, so lets return false as no user was
            // supplied and the user hasn't hit the limit globally yet either
            return FALSE;

        } else {
            
            // The login timeout is set, let see if it's expired or not?
            if ($this->login_timeout <= CURRENT_TIME) {
                if ($userid > 0) {
                    $user_info = $database->prepared_select("users", "WHERE uid = ? LIMIT 1", array($userid), "loginattempts, loginlockoutexpiry");
                    if ($user_info) {
                        if ($user_info["loginattempts"] >= $config->general->max_login_trys) {
                            if ($user_info["loginlockoutexpiry"] > $time) {
                                return TRUE;
                            } else {
                                $this->login_timeout = 0;
                                $this->login_attempts = 0;
                                $database->update_prepared_query("sessions", array("login_attempts" => $this->login_attempts, "lockout_time" => $this->login_timeout), array("sid" => $this->session_id));
                                $database->update_prepared_query("users", array("loginattempts" => 0, "loginlockoutexpiry" => 0), array("uid" => $userid));
                                return FALSE;
                            }
                        } else {
                            // The user they're trying for is not at the max tries so we can return false!
                            return FALSE;
                        }
                    } else {
                        // There was no user information found for this id, so we can't
                        // return a result and we will just return false instead
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                } else {
                    // The login timeout has expired for this guest account so
                    // we remove it globally!
                    $this->login_timeout = 0;
                    $this->login_attempts = 0;
                    $database->update_prepared_query("sessions", array("login_attempts" => $this->login_attempts, "lockout_time" => $this->login_timeout), array("sid" => $this->session_id));
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }

            // They must still be expired, so lets return true!
            return TRUE;

        }

    }

    return FALSE;

}
```

Does this seem like a good userflow and does the function seem to be missing anything that you would suggest that could potentially lead to an error?

I have been troubleshooting it and all my conditions SEEM to be passing, but I've also spent about 100 hours on this application already and a fresh pair of eyes to suggest any holes I may have missed would be very beneficial at this point.

If it all looks good, let me know so I can stop going crazy overbuilding this thing!

Answer (score 1):

i just force expire the cookie it's quite simple its balance between being secure and provably annoying for brute force

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerate new cookie everytime page refresh
 $reload_userTimeout=40; // set the new cookie to expire 40seconds everytime user reload the page( they need to type the form in just 40 secs)
 setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$reload_userTimeout);


if (login detail wrong) {

 session_unset();
 session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerate new cookie
 $captchaWrong_userTimeout=15; // since they got login details wrong The cookie would now expire 15 secs ( shorter than before so they need to type fast as possible :p )
 setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$captchaWrong_userTimeout);

} else { // login detail is correct

 session_unset();
 session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerate new cookie
 $captchaCorrect_userTimeout=1; // force expire the cookie in just 1 second
 setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$captchaCorrect_userTimeout);
 session_write_close();  // prevent cookie from being overwritten ( user must clear web browser cookies or use incognito mode to overwrite the cookie )
}

?>
```